# Indexing SQLServer data with SOLR

Tags: sql-server, solr, indexing

What is the best way of syncing the database change with solr incremental indexing? What is the best way of getting MSSQL server data to be indexed by solr?

Thank so much in addvance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configure Solr for SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559528/configure-solr-for-sql-server)

Comment: Here's the question that could help you if you're going to need anything beyond one-time dump: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868789/trigger-solr-update-after-mysql-update/8869224#comment11095934_8869224

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr works with plugins. you will need to create your own data importer plugin that will be called in a periodically manner (based on notifications, time period that passed, etc). You will point your solr configuration to the class that will be called upon update.

Regarding your second Q, I used a text file, that holds a time date description. Each time Solr was started it looked at said file and retrieved from the DB the relevant data that was changed in the DB from that point on (the file is updated when the index is updated).

I would suggest reading a good solr/lucene book/guide such as lucidworks-solr-refguide-1.4 before getting started, so you will be sure that your architectural solution is correct

Comment: -1. "Solr works with plugins, you will need to create your own data importer plugin" -> no.